# Whats wrong with this batch file ,it find hundreds

Tags: batch-file

why when I run it first thing in the morning I get hundreds of results

```
@echo off
:: it only shows files on you pc that arrived that day. 
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
DIR  /b /s /a c:\*.* >todays.txt
set count=0
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=," %%G IN ("todays.txt") DO (call :sub1 "%%G")
echo Todays file count=%count%
pause
 :: end of program
    :sub1
      set dat=%~t1
      SET fdate=%dat:~0,8%
      if "%fdate%"=="%date%" (
      echo.%count%  %1 %dat%
      set /a count=%count%+1
     )
     goto :eof
```

why when I run it first thing in the morning I get hundreds of results

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and ask the obvious: are the results _wrong_?

Comment: What ya trying to do? Loop through files? Echo files? Delete them?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only interested in *files*, I'd change the `/a` switch (which does nothing) to `/a-d` to suppress directorynames which would be reported as a "file".

There's really no point in specifying `tokens=*` with a `delims` since the `tokens=*` will reproduce the line regardless.

Comment: `DIR /A` without specifying attribute filters doesn't do nothing, it is effectively a don't hold anything back command. It matches files, directories and reparse points regardless of their read only, hidden, system, indexed or ready for archiving status. In the case above, as you stated, it was unnecessary but a general user file enquiry would probably be better advised to use `DIR/A-D-S-L`.

Comment: @Compo : Ah `/a` for all then? Very good. Never used it without providing a specific attribute.